# How to 'decode' a UTF-8 String which is built upon gzipped byte array

Tags: java, utf-8, gzip

I got some legacy text data which is utf-8 encoded, but against a gzipped byte array.

I'm wondering whether I can get the raw data back

something like:

```
String text = "Hello World!";
byte[] binData = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] compressData = gzip(binData);//via GZIPOutputStream

//this is what I have
String encodedString = new String(compressData, "UTF-8");


assertEquals(text, smartDecode(encodedString));
```

Is it possible to provide a function like smartDecode to help me retrieve the original text 'Hello World!' back?

Comment: What is `smartDecode`? And ecoding a  `byte[]` to a `String` using UTF-8 sounds like a stupid idea.

Comment: like I said, it's some legacy data which incorrectly store byte[] (some are gzipped, some are not) as utf-8 string (rather than something else like base64). So the topic is not about "how to do things right", it's about "how to recover from bad things"

Comment: This is weird. How do you know that it is truly a valid UTF-8 byte sequence?

Comment: I checked some legacy code to make sure the String is UTF-8 based. Yet it does not take into account that the byte[] could be gzipped or raw.

Comment: Basically if `encodedString` is what you have, then you're out of luck. It is exceedingly unlikely that the original `compressData` represented only correct UTF-8 sequences, which is the only way that you could reproduce `binData` from `encodedString`. If there were any "decoding errors", then you've already lost data  at this point (and as I said, the odds of decoding errors are very high).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! From my observation, encodedString is totally messed up, and encodedString.getBytes("UTF-8") returns more bytes than compressData. I was thinking maybe some trick can be played to map a bigger byte[] into a small one, but according to your feedback, it seems undoable :(

Comment: @JoachimSauer can I say encodedString has already lost the 'source of truth"? Say we have encodedString = f(text), and we almost can't have a reverse function to make text = g(encodedString), right?

Comment: @anuni: yes, almost always. Basically if `compressData` contains any byte sequence that isn't valid UTF-8, then it will be replaced with a unicode replacement symbol in `encodedString` which does *not* encode the faulty data, but basically just says "things went wrong here". So unless you're incredibly lucky, the process is not reversible.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!